# Import Scikit Learn Models or other proprietary models into H2O via Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, h2o

I have sample model built using python and scitkit learn, panda frames etc. I want to be able to import and view/run that model in H2O. After looking at the import and save options in the H2O library, it requires proprietary use of the H2O API to do any sort of importing or saving of models not created with the H2O algorithms.

Question: 
Are there ways around forcing the use the H2O algorithms and allowing the saving of models from other proprietors using the H2O API?

Below: this is the current approach to saving a model in H2O, but does not allow interaction with proprietary objects like pandas.

If I build my model using scikit learn algorithm and try to save it in H2O, the API disallows it.

Attempting to Save the below clf model using the H2O h2o.save_model method fails.

```
# Train Test Model
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2, random_state=seed)
clf.fit(x, labels)

# build the model
model = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(params)
model.train(params)

# save the model
# This works
model_path = h2o.save_model(model=model, path="/tmp/mymodel", force=True)
# This doesn't work
model_path = h2o.save_model(model=clf, path="/tmp/mymodel", force=True)
print model_path
/tmp/mymodel/DeepLearning_model_python_1441838096933

# load the model
saved_model = h2o.load_model(model_path)

# download the model built above to your local machine
my_local_model = h2o.download_model(model, path="/Users/UserName/Desktop")

# upload the model that you just downloded above
# to the H2O cluster
uploaded_model = h2o.upload_model(my_local_model)
```

Comment: What is your goal of using h2.save_model() to save an sklearn model? H2O and Sklearn are different libraries and have different dependencies. They are designed independently and the functions from each cannot be interchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The goal was to use H2O has the primary model profiling tool as well as to provide a richer interface for comparing metrics etc. As discovered H2O is not compatible with other proprietary models and does not include wrappers to convert them.